# How can I include a JavaScript file on a web page only if the browser is IE 7 or earlier?

Tags: javascript, html, json, internet-explorer

How to include a java script file based on a condition.

To be more specific, I want to include a JavaScript file that gives JSON support if the browser is IE and the version is less than eight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use conditional comments http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]> 
     <script src="yourscript.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```